# Parsing Cassandra commit log

Tags: parsing, cassandra

Two days I've been searching for some tool, or an **instrument for parsing (into readable format) Cassandra commit log**, but I didn't find anything appropriate for it.
Does anyone know something about it?

Thanks in advance, hoping for a helpful answers.

Comment: in newer versions you can use CommitLogReader. See https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/audit_logging.html for more details